# Dagger 2 - modules from different components

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am not quite sure how to solve this with dagger 2.
Lets assume we have `ApplicationModule` that provides us `ApplicationContext`
then we have `ApplicationComponent` that uses just this one module.
Then on top of it we have `ActivityModule` and `ActivityComponent` that has dependency on `ApplicationComponent`.
`ActivityComponent` is build just like

```
    ApplicationComponent component = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent();

    mComponent = Dagger_ActivityComponent.builder()
            .applicationComponent(component)
            .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
            .build();
```

And then I inject my activity:

```
mComponent.inject(this);
```

Now I am able to use everything that is declared inside my `ActivityModule`, however it is not possible for me to access `ApplicationModule`.

So the question is how could that be achieved? So that when I build component that depends on another component I can still access module from the first one?

## EDIT

I think I have found solutions, after rewatching [Devoxx talk by Jake](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/5471cdd1e4b065ebcfa1d557/) again, I have had to miss that out, whatever I want to use from another components module I have to provide in that component, for example I want to use Context from `ApplicationModule` then inside `ApplicationComponent` I have to state `Context provideContext();` and it is going to be available. Pretty cool :)

Comment: Would you mind posting the link to the talk? Thanks

Comment: Here you are https://parleys.com/play/5471cdd1e4b065ebcfa1d557

Comment: You should post your edit as the answer and select it. On a side note, have you figured out scopes in Dagger 2? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411352/what-determines-the-lifecycle-of-a-component-object-graph-in-dagger-2

Comment: I don't think they use `Dagger_` prefixes anymore...

Comment: They do, just w/o underscore -> `DaggerActivityComponent`

Answer (score 17):

You have already answered your question, but the answer is to specify the provision methods in your "superscoped" component (ApplicationComponent).

For example,

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Something something() {
        return new Something.Builder().configure().build(); 
           // if Something can be made with constructor, 
           // use @Singleton on the class and @Inject on the constructor
           // and then the module is not needed
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules={ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Something something(); //PROVISION METHOD. YOU NEED THIS.
}

@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {
}

@ActivityScope
public class OtherThing {
    private final Something something;

    @Inject
    public OtherThing(Something something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
}

@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class})
@ActivityScope
public interface ActivityComponent extends ApplicationComponent { //inherit provision methods
    OtherThing otherThing();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to `extends ApplicationComponent`?

Comment: @mbmc you are doing that to inherit the provision methods (which is `Something something();`) - if you don't inherit, then I think you won't be able to subscope the `ActivityComponent` if you ever need it.

Comment: Seems that setting the dependency is sufficient to access the provision methods from the parent component.

Comment: @mbmc you're right, setting the dependency (App component) in the Activity component will grant this latter to inject anything scoped to be used on the Activity.

Comment: Cannot find annotation @ActivityScope

Comment: added activity scope